# Running Freepascal compiler in a docker container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, freepascal, fpc, ubuntu-14.10

I want to use the Freepascal compiler inside a docker container, came from ubuntu 14.10 image. When I want to install it via apt-get install fp-compiler or fp-compiler-2.6.2 I got the error package not found. But if I browse the package list online it should be there? Did the ubuntu docker image use a different package list? 
Is there another way to get fpc works inside a docker container?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do an `apt-get update` first - the images don't ship with package lists as they would just get out of date and cause issues.